# How to read value from Excel MetaProperty

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I want to read and write the value of an Excel MetaProperty. The propety can be found via the ID.
But any access to the property value leads to an exception.
Thanks for help.

```
Excel.Workbook workbook
Microsoft.Office.Core.MetaProperties metaProps = workbook.ContentTypeProperties;
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Core.MetaProperty propy in metaProps)
{
    if (propy.Id == "Name")
    {
        var a = propy.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exception do you get? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: Do you get the same error in VBA?

Comment: When debugging, almost all properties of the variable propy has as value: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Element not found. (HRESULT: 0x80070490).

Comment: Do you get the same in case of value?

Comment: ID can be accessed, but not value. Therefore, the exception raises when reading value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the late-binding technology for accessing the property value. See [Type.InvokeMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.invokemember?view=net-6.0) for more information.